# Python server will not terminate on Ctrl+C after a request has come in

Tags: python, http, server

I'm dabbling with Python and HTTP. Have created this simple server script I run with `python cli.py serve`. The server starts and works, but the keyboard interrupt Ctrl+C only gets trough on the next page refresh, not when I actually press Ctrl+C in the terminal.. Any fix for this? Note: works immediately when no request have come in yet.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import sys, signal

commands = ["serve"]

class Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/":
            self.path = "/index.html"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("Tere, maailm!!",'utf-8'))


if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] in commands:
    index = commands.index(sys.argv[1])
    if index == 0: # serve command
        print("Starting web server. Press Ctrl+C to exit!")
        httpd = HTTPServer(("localhost", 8080), Server)
        try:
            httpd.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Shutting down...")
            httpd.socket.close()
            sys.exit(0)
else:
    print("Usage: python tab.py [command], where [command] is any of", commands)
```

Comment: Is what you are saying different than this? `$ python3 test.py serve
Starting web server. Press Ctrl+C to exit!
^CShutting down...
$` Because it seems to shut down when I use `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: When you send Ctrl-C the server gets a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, but it's probably stuck in a `socket.accept()` call (which is an uninterruptible IO wait state). You can simply connect to the socket (e.g. using a tool like `telnet` or `netcat`) to break out of the wait state. In a more robust environment, you would use a dedicated WSGI server which should take care of this sort of thing.

Comment: @agaidis that only works when no requests have come in. Try actually going to localhost:8080 and see it won't quit after the first page visit

Answer (score 2):

Same problem...
I discovered ThreadingHTTPServer, that works (instead of HTTPServer)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31339326)